# Error in looping so that a quiz's math query repeats itself

Tags: python, math, error-handling

I have a piece of coding that is most basically a quiz. I had error handling so that if someone pressed a letter or anything other than a number, it would carry on with the quiz instead of letting the person attempt another question. (For example, if question 5 was 2+3 and they entered t, then it would carry on and not give them a different question for question 5). 
I tried to update the coding, so it would loop:

```
def random_question():#defines function to get random question
count = 0#equates count to 0
for number in range (0,10):#makes the code generate the question 10 times
    try:#the code makes it so the computer tries one thing and is the beggining
        questionList = [random_sum,random_subtraction,random_times]#puts functions in a list to be called on
        randomQuestion = random.choice(questionList)#calls on the list to generate the random questions
        randomQuestion()#calls on variable
        except ValueError:#if there is a value error or a type error it will notice it and try to stop it
            print ("Please enter a number")#prints out the statement if there is a type error or a value error
            else:
                break
random_question()#calls on the function random_question
```

However, it comes up with a syntax error, and highlights the 'except' part next to the ValueError.

Any help as to why this is would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your except statement should have the same indention as your try statement. In your sample code it is indented an extra tab which would cause that error.

Python takes indention seriously and it is often the culprit. I'm unclear if your def line is a place holder or if this code is part of it, but if this code is part of the function definition you have other indention issues to worry about.

I'd suggest going through it carefully and making sure everything is lined up properly. The basic rule of thumb is, if something is part of something else, it is indented under it.

```
def something():
    step 1
    step 2
    if (condition):
        the true thing
    else:
        the false thing
    while (something):
        repeat something
this is not part of the function anymore
```